# How to Creating elastic Search server at their local machine?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have installed Java version 1.8.0_73 or later.

please suggest the later steps to configure it

Answer (score 1):

Just follow official guide how to install Elasticsearch on Windows - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html

Another way, maybe easier, to install Docker and then run Elasticsearch just with one command, more details here - https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/

Answer (score 1):

Steps are as follows :

Step1 :  Download the latest version of the elastic Search from elastic.co website

Step2 : Install the latest JDK in your machine. must be 1.8 or later.

Step3 : Set the bin path of jre as JAVA_HOME in environment variable.

Step4 : open the command prompt and move to the elasticsearch bin folder then type elasticsearch.

OR

Step4 : goto the elasticsearch bin folder run the service.bat file and elasticsearch.bat file.

Step5 : goto browser and check this url http://localhost:9200/ you must get JSON in return if so, then you have successfully configure the elasticsearch at your machine.

Comment: thanx Amar for the valueable answer.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to install elasticsearch is to use homebrew:

[Linux](http://linuxbrew.sh)

[OS X](https://brew.sh/index_fr.html)

Then you can just type:

```
brew install elasticsearch
brew services start elasticsearch
```